# React Js onClick inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `ul` `li` list inside the `render` method and there is an `onClick` event on `li` which call `this.handleClick` function and state gets changed

```
var InspirationFilter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {currentFilterText:"Top All Time", currentFilter:"top_all_time", showUl:false};
    },
    handleClick: function(filter, filterText){
        this.setState({currentFilterText:filterText, currentFilter:filter, showUl:!this.state.showUl});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={this.handleClick('top_all_time', 'Top All Time')}>Top All Time</li>
                  <li onClick={this.handleClick('top_this_week', 'Top This Week')}>Top Week</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleClick('top_this_month', 'Top This Month')}>Top Month</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

But this code gives me the error

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure
>   function of props and state

I tried to use bind with the click event like this,

```
return (
    <ul>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,'top_all_time', 'Top All Time')}>Top All Time</li>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,'top_this_week', 'Top This Week')}>Top  Week</li>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this.'top_this_month', 'Top This Month')}>Top  Month</li>
    </ul>
);
```

The above error is gone now but ran into another error which is as follows,

> Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component.
>   React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so
>   you can safely remove this call. See InspirationFilter

In the react documentation [Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) they are also using the `bind` method.

Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: You're third `li` has a `.` after `this` instead of `,` - is that in your source code or just here?

Comment: What version of React are you using? I'm not able to recreate the issue in the second example. FWIW it's not an error, just a warning

Comment: @Mat yes that was my mistake regarding the `(dot)`. Now the click event is working but i am still having the warning. Is there is any better way to do it without warning?

Comment: I am using `React v0.14.1`

Comment: I'll try to replicate, in the meantime try binding `null` instead of `this` when you are binding your parameters

Comment: Binding `null` still gives the warning.

Comment: Try updating to `v0.14.2`, I'm not able to replicate in my environment

Comment: Upgraded to `v0.14.2` still having the same warning. I think i can live with that warning if it is not evil?

Comment: No, you can leave it. But it's strange..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that onClick value has to be a function, so just create a helper method that creates such a function for you:

```
createClickHandler: function(filter, filterText){
    return function() {
        this.setState({...});
    }.bind(this);
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li onClick={this.createClickHandler('top_all_time', 'Top All Time')}>Top All Time</li>
            <li onClick={this.createClickHandler('top_this_week', 'Top This Week')}>Top Week</li>
            <li onClick={this.createClickHandler('top_this_month', 'Top This Month')}>Top Month</li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

React is really just a bit over-helpful here with its warning. Your reason for using `bind()` is no to bind `this`, but rather to bind the arguments.

**Why it works?** This solution avoids the re-binding warning because it's not re-binding an already bound `this.handleClick`, but instead creating a new function (that's not yet bound to anything) and binding that.

Comment: That doesn't solve his problem and is incorrect JSX syntax, it's actually the same as the first example he gave which invokes the function instead of passing a reference to it

Comment: The issue is that you pass functions in React as a reference to that function, you're invoking it instead. Meaning the correct syntax is `onClick={this.myFunction}` not `onClick={this.myFunction()}`

Comment: The contents of `{...}` can be any valid JavaScript expression. For `onClick` the expression must evaluate to a function, which I think my code does.

Comment: But your code _invokes_ the function, meaning if you change state in your function you have an infinite loop, which is why in the same example he was getting an error. Read the question again..

Comment: No. During `render()` my code only invokes `createClickHandler()` which returns a function that's assigned to onClick. Only when onClick finally fires will it call the created function, that in turn calls `setState()`.

Comment: Oh jeez, that's what I get for not reading carefully enough.. my apologies

Comment: Though it shouldn't solve his issue, since you're essentially doing the same thing as he is in his second example. Weird issue

Comment: @Mat his code did solve the problem. Thanks to both of you for your help

Comment: oh.. ok glad to hear it, I don't understand why it solves it though

Comment: @Mat Added an explanation of why this workaround removes the warning.

Comment: Thanks for adding additional explanation, but it doesn't make sense to me. I recreated his code and I never got the warning. I understand why you're code works and why it solves this case, I don't understand how this case comes about though. I suppose a function named `handleClick` is automatically bound to `this`? I haven't seen that in any of my react projects.

Comment: Maybe you're not ES6 classes intead of React.createClass()? https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Answer (score 3):

To summarize, in your first example, when you use this format:

```
onClick={this.functionName(arg1, arg2)
```

you are calling the functions rather than providing a reference to the functions. Hence they are being called directly every time it is being rendered rather than onClick as intended.

When you use the format:

```
onClick={this.functionName.bind(this, arg1, arg2)}
```

you are providing a reference to the function and binding context and arguments, rather than calling it. This is the correct method; ignore the warnings (even though there are way too many and it's really annoying)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to pass a function to `onClick`.

You have a typo on the third `<li>`

```
return (
    <ul>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,'top_all_time', 'Top All Time')}>Top All Time</li>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,'top_this_week', 'Top This Week')}>Top  Week</li>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'top_this_month', 'Top This Month')}>Top  Month</li>
    </ul>
);
```

Check this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/20047/ It works on React 0.14