# Binding to event handler that calls setState in ComponentDidMount produces warning

Tags: reactjs

I'm using jQuery to create event bindings in a ReactJS component's `componentDidMount` function, which seems like the right place to do this.

```
$('body').on('defaultSearchContext.registerQueryEditor', (function(_this) {
  return function(event, component) {
    _this.setState({
      queryEditors: _this.state.queryEditors.concat([component])
    });
  };
})(this));
```

This code isn't actually run on componentDidMount, it's simply setting up the binding that later calls `setState` when the event fires. However, this generates the following warning every time this event triggers, which pollutes my console with dozens of warnings:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I have tried moving the `setState` code to a separate function like `onEvent` and calling that from the binding in `componentDidMount` but the warning is still produced.

Ideally, I'd like to create the binding in the proper place, indeed, there is some issue with doing it in `componentDidMount`. If not, I'd like to know if it's possible to silence the warning, or whether I should perhaps file a bug for ReactJS itself. If it helps, I'm using ReactJS 0.14.3 (latest at this time).

This is similar to, but not the same as [React Js onClick inside render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554611/react-js-onclick-inside-render). In that case, the solution is to return an anonymous function to onClick, but that doesn't seem applicable to my situation.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery instead of Reacts synthetic events? Also can you please provide your render and any other relevant methods so we can get the whole picture?

Comment: @DDurham I suppose I'm not using synthetic events because I'm not familiar with them. If you could point me to any useful docs, or ideally a code sample of how to replace my jQuery code with them, that would be awesome. As for the rest of the code, this component doesn't render, it simply dispatches events, so the render method simply returns false. I've tried removing the code included in my question and the warning goes away, so I'm pretty certain that's the issue.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Comment: @DDurham thanks, I had already found that page but it is lacking examples, so I'm really stumped as to how to bind to/trigger events. To be clear, these events are arbitrary events I'm triggering from other components, not standard interaction events like `onClick`, etc

Comment: @swrobel what event are you trying to bind against?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

Comment: @Tyrsius this is basically an event dispatcher component that fires off a query to ElasticSearch when other components trigger an event. This particular event, however, is simply registering each of those components so that their modifications to the query can be combined before sending it off. I suppose the issue could be that each other components `componentDidMount` has the following code: `$(PUBSUB_NODE).trigger('defaultSearchContext.registerQueryEditor', this)`, although the React backtrace points to the event handler code included above.

Comment: I wouldn't use DOM events for that. Just pass a function down from this component that is used by lower components. If you want an example, I can provide one

Comment: @Tyrsius that would be great, but the "lower components" aren't rendered by this component (they aren't children of it), so I don't think it will work in that way. If you have an example that works around that, it'd be very helpful!

Comment: What are they rendered by? The use case here is communicating between independent components, which in React is usually done by a store. Patterns for this include Redux and Flux.

Comment: @Tyrsius they are, indeed, independent components. This seems like a pretty simple use case to me, since there are just a few shared interactions without much shared state, but perhaps it's time for me to investigate Redux or Flux. Thanks!

Comment: If its just a few interactions, those will indeed be overkill. It sounds like you want a simple event system, you don't need DOM events for that. I'll make an answer.

Comment: @DDurham fyi, jQuery's `on` just seems to be an elaborate wrapper around standard javascript `window.addEventListener`, which is what the [article](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html) you linked me to recommended. Regardless, I tried your suggestion and the warning persisted.

Comment: @swrobel I added that answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to coordinate events between independent components. This is a fairly standard thing to do, and it doesn't require DOM events. The standard practice for doing this in React is to use a store/dispatcher pattern like [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) or [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) (I personally prefer redux). However, if this is part of a larger, not-completely-React application, then this may not be possible. If it is just for a small piece of an React app, it may still be overkill.

All you need is an object to coordinate events. An event is just a collection of callbacks, possibly typed or keyed. This requires nothing more than an object shared between two places. DOM Events are overkill; jQuery is overkill. You just need to trigger a callback.

This is a **VERY SIMPLE** event coordinator.

```
let simpleEventCoordinator = {
  callbacks: new Map(),
  getHandler(eventKey) {
    let handler = this.callbacks.get(eventKey);
    if (!handler) {
      handler = new Set();
      this.callbacks.set(eventKey, handler);
    }
    return handler;
  },
  registerCallback(eventKey, callback) {
    this.getHandler(eventKey).add(callback);    
  },
  removeCallback(eventKey, callback) {
    this.getHandler(eventKey).delete(callback);
  },
  trigger(eventKey, data) {
    this.getHandler(eventKey).forEach(c => c(data));
  }
```

Keep a map of callbacks, which will be `nameOfEvent => callback()`. Call them when asked. Pretty straightforward.

I know nothing about how your components are structured, but you said they are independent. Let's say they look like this:

```
React.render((
  <div>
    <QueryManager />
    <button onClick={() => simpleEvent.trigger('event')}>{'Update'}</button>
  </div>
), document.body);
```

This is all your component needs to handle this event

```
  componentDidMount() {
    simpleEvent.registerCallback('event', this.update);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    simpleEvent.removeCallback('event', this.update);
  }
  update() {
    //do some stuff
  }
```

I've put together a **very simple** [codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/KVgwqB?editors=001) demonstrating this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code of where that warning is coming from](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/951f3b6ba89d893479b1bbb6dc523aa3239ab46f/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactUpdateQueue.js#L50), it appears that if some reference is maintained before an update is about to happen, it throws that warning. So maybe the way your mixing the jQuery events and react is creating a memory leak? Its hard to say exactly because of the lack of surrounding code to your snippet what else could be going on.

Comment: Wish I understood the ReactJS code better, but, for reference, [this is the  source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.3/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactUpdateQueue.js#L50) from v0.14.3 where it is coming from